# In a tile-based terrain, how to check if there's a tile adiacent to another one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a dynamic texture system for my procedurally generated tile-based terrain.
I based my project on this guide:
http://community.playstarbound.com/threads/how-tile-textures-work.44646/
but i can't figure out how to implement an update system.

What i mean is that when i place a new tile how can i check if on the right/left/bottom/top there's another one so to connect the textures?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention anything about structure where you are storing tiles.
Basically there should be two dimensional array where each tile is stored in certain place (row and column are corresponding to array dimensions).

So if you are checking tile on position [3][3], then you should also check all it's neighbours (up: 3,2; down: 3,4; left: 2,3; right: 4,3). Some tiles require also to check diagonal tiles as well. Read more about autotiles. There is a plenty of good material about it in Internet.